# Java: Why can't I write delimited String to a file using a BufferedReader?

Tags: java

I've come across a strange problem when I delimit a String (I eventually want to delimit by the < and > characters), I can then output this to the screen but when I try to write to a textfile I get an arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
    System.out.println(s[index]);
    String[] finalSplit = s[index].split("\\>");
    System.out.println(s[index]+finalSplit.length);
    System.out.println(finalSplit[1]);
    bufOut.write(finalSplit[1]);
```

Sample output from the above is as follows:

```
    <env:MessageSentDateTime>2011-11-17T11:22:33.456Z</env:MessageSentDateTime>
    <env:MessageSentDateTime>2011-11-17T11:22:33.456Z</env:MessageSentDateTime>2
    2011-11-17T11:22:33.456Z</env:MessageSentDateTime

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
          at Main.main(main.java:81)
```

If I don't do the split then I can write the whole thing to the text file but I only want the information out of the middle.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Of course your array is not getting split. Check the length of array after split.

Comment: It is. It prints the `finalSplit.length` as 2(second line in the output).

Comment: @YogendraSingh. Oh. didn't notice that.

Comment: @user1847802: Can you post few more lines of your stack trace?

Comment: I have found my problem thank you, after checking the output a little more carefully I saw that I was getting items from s with no content, hence the error.  Thank you for redirecting my attention to the trace guys.

Answer (score 0):

In line

```
System.out.println(finalSplit[1]);
```

you are accessing element 1 which does not exist, because the splitting moved all to finalSplit[0]. Change your split delimiter (e.g ">")

Comment: Problem of not being thorough enough about what was getting through to this code, was getting empty and incomplete strings finding their way through.  Managed to fix it now, thank you for everybody's suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, which `BufferedOutStream` are you using. Below work fine(you need to pass `byte[]` to `write` method):

```
String s=
    "<env:MessageSentDateTime>2011-11-17T11:22:33.456Z</env:MessageSentDateTime>";
String[] finalSplit  = s.split("\\>");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                                 new FileOutputStream(new File("delimited.txt")));
bos.write(finalSplit[1].getBytes());
bos.close();
```

It writes: `2011-11-17T11:22:33.456Z</env:MessageSentDateTime` in `delimited.txt` file.

Comment: My code looks like yours as far as the bufferedWriter I'm using goes, it really was just a problem with what I was passing to the code I posted.  With a little more care on my part I could have saved you wasting your time, sorry and thank you

Comment: @user1847802: :) That is what I said, it looked fine to me. Just to know, which Buffered Out Stream are you using, which takes String?

Comment: 'code'FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter(newFilePath);
'code'BufferedWriter bufOut = new BufferedWriter(outFile);